# How do I get the Gold Standard?

Tags: quarrel

I was playing Domination in Quarrel (on XBLA), and when I finished the battle, I got a Silver Standard.

I am assuming that there is probably a Gold (and maybe a Bronze?) standard for each level/battle.

How do I make sure I get the Gold Standard on every level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a Gold standard if you manage to complete the given objectives without making any mistakes, such as losing a piece of your land.

I believe that for each time you mess up, you get knocked down to the next best standard. E.g, Gold -> Silver.

Comment: Where do you see what the objective is?

Comment: It should be under your character icon on the Domination Domain select screen, your character avatar (e.g., the ninja/pirate) tells you who control what territory and which you need to liberate.